# Objective-C/iOS - Is it possible to compile a private framework into another private framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks

Several friends have created a few private frameworks in objective-c and I want to create my own private framework that uses their private frameworks that they have sent me as a wrapper around theirs. Is this possible? I want to give my framework to other people and they be unaware that they are using other frameworks because mine takes all the commonalities between the different frameworks to make it easier to perform certain actions.

```
Framework A
   action 1 
   action 2

Framework B 
   action 1 
   action 2

 My framework 
   action 1 chooses to use action 1 from either 
   framework provided by the data passed into the method
   action 2 chooses to use action 2 from either 
   framework provided by the data passed into the method
```

Comment: Yes, it is. What have you tried so far and where did you run into a problem?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad I have tried to just include it without exposing the headers but when I compile I get errors thrown about files missing.

Comment: You have to export the headers.

Comment: So, there is no way to hide the headers?

If not, would they be aware that it is using several different other frameworks? Or would they just be aware that they are using mine?

Comment: As long as you want to give the user the chance to use something from the framework, you have to show the declarations in the headers. However, why do you want to hide them?

Comment: My buddies don't want it known that it is their work inside the various systems. They prefer it to look as if it is my work. 

The user will not be using anything from their frameworks. My framework will be using the various frameworks.

Comment: I think static libraries would do the trick for you. If your friends provide you A.a and B.a static libraries and you link your framework against them, you should be able to hide traces of other libraries.

Comment: @batu What if they do not know how to do that? Or, quite frankly, if they do not want to do it at all? lol

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I discovered that this was a code signing issue. The app that uses MyFramework throws an error because it doesn't sign the nested frameworks. In order to do this, you have to tell the app that uses MyFramework to code sign nested frameworks in the build phases via run shell script:

```
pushd ${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/Frameworks/MyFramework.framework/Frameworks
for EACH in *.framework; do
   echo "-- signing ${EACH}"
   /usr/bin/codesign --force --deep --sign 
"${EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY}" --entitlements 
"${TARGET_TEMP_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app.xcent" --timestamp=none $EACH
done
popd
```